# Keycloak import users from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, keycloak

I've jsut started to work with Keycloak. Previously we used simple MySQL DB to store user's hash-passwords in `crypt-sha512`
So now the question is how to migrate all users from MySQL to keycloak. I saw some PasswordHashProvider for keycloak, but don't understand, how to use it. Can you explain it to me like to a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a simple solution to this. I’m looking for this option too. For now I found this option: https://technology.first8.nl/programmatically-adding-users-in-keycloak/